# How to find Azure Subscription Quota

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-roles

I did google and could not find any accurate answer.

When I try to deploy the web application to different data centre, I am getting error message below:

```
    Server response = 40652 Cannot move or create server. 
Subscription 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx' will exceed server quota.
```

Could someone please help me understand below:

1. Where do I find the max quota for given subscription within a management portal?
2. Does error above means the quota exceeded for Azure SQL Server or Host services.
3. How many servers can one subscription create?

I used Cerebrata cloud management studio which shows the subscription detail below:

> Cores: 9 / 20
>   Hosted Services: 4 / 20
>   Storage: 8 / 20

Not sure whether Azure SQL Server belongs to hosted service or storage or something else that's not shown above.

Thanks.

Comment: How much are you trying to deploy? Remember that a Medium instance has 2 Cores, so if your deployment is set to 6+ instances, that will exceed your Core quota

Answer (score 15):

For Azure SQL Servers, there is a hidden default max of 6 Azure SQL SERVERS (Not databases). Once you attempt to create the 7th, you will receive this error: New-AzureSqlDatabaseServer : Cannot move or create server. Subscription 'XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX' will exceed 
server quota. Submit a billing request to increase the quota limit on SQL Azure Servers.

Answer (score 7):

You can find the quota information in the azure management portal. Scroll through the list of items in the left bar and at the end you will find "Settings". When you click "Settings" and switch to "Usage" tab you can see quota information as in the screenshot below.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think portal exposes this functionality (or at least I could not find it :)). However if you're interested in finding about quota information about some of the services, you can do so programmatically by performing `Get Subscription` operation on your subscription: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh403995.aspx. This operation would tell you how many cores available to you in your subscription, how many storage accounts and cloud services you can create in your subscription.

At least these details are available through Azure Management Studio/Cloud Storage Studio from Cerebrata (http://www.cerebrata.com) as well, if you're looking for 3rd party tools. After you add a subscription there, just right click on your subscription node and click on `View Subscription Properties`.

You could also find the quota information on pricing page as well: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/offers/commitment-plans (Just scroll down to Usage Quotas section).

One last comment: You could easily increase the quota by contacting customer support. The link is there in the pricing page link I mentioned above.

**Update**

As far as quota for SQL Azure is concerned, I could find a limit on the maximum number of database servers allowed per subscription however there's a limit of 149 user databases (150 including `master` database) / server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336245.aspx#dcasl. Can you ensure you're not exceeding that quota?

Comment: thank you. But it's weird why I get the quota exceed error when I've this:
Cores: 9 / 20 
Hosted Services: 4 / 20 
Storage: 8 / 20

Comment: Updated my answer to include some quota information about SQL Azure.